How to group INSERT and UPDATE statements together inside a "MERGE" statement
I have been trying to group INSERT and UPDATE statements together in a MERGE statement with the following condition:

Key: location_cd, machine_cd, product_cd
If the status of the current record is 0, the status of the data input is 1, then insert a new record and update current record with [lastest_flag]column's value from "1" to "0".
Otherwise, just update status of current record.

Sample Table: tableA



location_cd
machine_cd
product_cd
status
lastest_flag
updated_timestamp




0012345678
1234567890
123456
1
1
2024/06/10 15:30:15


0012345678
1234567890
111111
0
1
2024/06/10 15:30:15



Input data: input1



location_cd
machine_cd
product_cd
status
updated_timestamp




0012345678
1234567890
123456
0
2024/06/10 15:40:15



Input data: input2



location_cd
machine_cd
product_cd
status
updated_timestamp




0012345678
1234567890
111111
1
2024/06/10 15:40:15



Expected output:

with input1 we will use UPDATE statement.
with input2 we will INSERT new record and update status of current record.




location_cd
machine_cd
product_cd
status
lastest_flag
updated_timestamp
action




0012345678
1234567890
123456
0
1
2024/06/10 15:40:15
update


0012345678
1234567890
111111
0
0
2024/06/10 15:30:15
update


0012345678
1234567890
111111
1
1
2024/06/10 15:40:15
new record



I tried this, but it is not working.

Define input data
DECLARE @input_data TABLE 
(
    location_cd varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    machine_cd varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    product_cd varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    status varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    updated_timestamp varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @input_data
VALUES ('0012345678','1234567890','123456','0','2024/06/10 15:40:15'),
       ('0012345678','1234567890','111111','1','2024/06/10 15:40:15')


Here is my SQL with the MERGE statement. When I ran it, I got error:

Error 156 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'

MERGE INTO tableA AS Target
USING @input_data AS Source
                  ON Target.location_cd = Source.location_cd
                  AND Target.machine_cd = Source.machine_cd
                  AND Target.product_cd = Source.product_cd

WHEN MATCHED AND Target.status = 1 AND Source.status = 0 AND Target.updated_timestamp < Source.updated_timestamp 
    THEN
        UPDATE SET
            Target.status = Source.status,
            Target.updated_timestamp = Source.updated_timestamp

WHEN MATCHED AND Target.status = 0 AND Source.status = 1 AND Target.updated_timestamp < Source.updated_timestamp 
    THEN
    BEGIN
        INSERT (machine_cd, location_cd, product_cd, status, lastest_flag, updated_timestamp)
        VALUES (Source.machine_cd, Source.location_cd, Source.product_cd, Source.status, '1', Source.updated_timestamp);

        UPDATE 
            SET Target.lastest_flag = '0';
    END;




If you are using MERGE, then some suggested reading.

This simply isn't how the MERGE syntax works.

Why are you putting a BEGIN...END inside the MERGE?

Also, what is the sense of inserting a record, if you matched the record? Shouldn't you be updating the record.

When you start writing a question about merge, it should always be a sign you shouldn't be using it, it's buggy, easy to go wrong and doesn't support complex scenarios like yours since you cannot do two actions for same row. Although, if you're lucky, you can use an OUTPUT clause of the merge to simulate the INSERT, since you can access the source/target columns in the output. Finally, columns containing words first, last, best, latest is a sign your design is not correct and you have denormalized data.

@Thom A
Well I asked chatGPT about how to group insert and update statements together inside MERGE statement by using WHEN MATCHED. And they suggested me using BEGIN...END.

"I asked chatGPT" That was your first mistake. There is a reason why LLMs are banned here; the text they vomit out can (and often is) incorrect or unreliable. A visit to the documentation would have quickly shown you that syntax was invalid, and the error you got only further cemented that.

@MarkRotteveel i'm guessing this is a manual emulation of a temporal table

@siggemannen I'm not sure if you really understand what I'm talking about. The data I gave is just an example, it may have some confusion but I don't think it's really important for you to focus on it. The problem I am talking about is whether it is possible to simultaneously perform INSERT new record and UPDATE data of current data inside MERGE? If you have a solution, I would really appreciate it if you shared it, but if you don't know, you can take a look at this ticket.

My solution is don't use a MERGE statement since it's usually incorrect solution, and it won't work with your case. Use separate insert/update statements. Well, technically you can perhaps make 3/4 parts work with merge, but you still need a second update statement. If you're beginner, it's usually not worth the hassle.

It's not possible to specify multiple actions per merged row in a MERGE statement. Each row can only have one action done to it. You can also only have a maxmimum of two WHEN MATCHED clauses, and one must have UPDATE and the other DELETE, so instead you are going to have to squash them together. All in all, it ends up being that you don't even need MERGE, you can just use a normal joined UPDATE.
You can however use an OUTPUT clause to output data into the same or another table. But OUTPUT is only specified once on the whole statement, so you are either going to need to output to another table variable, then conditionally insert from there, or you can do two separate statements, only one with OUTPUT.
UPDATE t
SET
    status = s.status,
    updated_timestamp = s.updated_timestamp
FROM tableA AS t
JOIN @input_data AS s
  ON t.location_cd = s.location_cd
 AND t.machine_cd = s.machine_cd
 AND t.product_cd = s.product_cd
WHERE t.status = 1
  AND s.status = 0
  AND t.updated_timestamp < s.updated_timestamp;


UPDATE t
SET lastest_flag = '0'  -- why is this a string?

OUTPUT
    s.machine_cd, s.location_cd, s.product_cd, s.status, '1', s.updated_timestamp
INTO tableA
    (machine_cd, location_cd, product_cd, status, lastest_flag, updated_timestamp)

FROM tableA AS t
JOIN @input_data AS s
  ON t.location_cd = s.location_cd
 AND t.machine_cd = s.machine_cd
 AND t.product_cd = s.product_cd
WHERE t.status = 0
  AND s.status = 1
  AND t.updated_timestamp < s.updated_timestamp;

